# Autolayout issue with top & bottom layout guide

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have some problem to set NSLayoutconstraints programmatically from my view and controller.topLayoutGuide & controller.bottomLayoutGuide.

with this code in viewDidLoad:

```
_mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:_mainView];
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_mainView]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_mainView)]];
id top = self.topLayoutGuide;
id bottom = self.bottomLayoutGuide;
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[top]-0-[_mainView]-0-[bottom]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(top, _mainView, bottom)]];
[self.view layoutSubviews];
```

the result is that:

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/2h34shh.png]

(_mainView has dark gray background color)

if i set up the constraints relative to the superview it works:

```
_mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:_mainView];
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_mainView]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_mainView)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_mainView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_mainView)]];
[self.view layoutSubviews];
```

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/24ouiop.png]

where is my error?
the view controller hierarchy is uitabbarcontroller -> uinavigationController -> myViewController

---

SOLVED!

the error was:

```
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
```

I changed the code with

```
for(NSLayoutConstraint *c in self.view.constraints)
    if(c.firstItem == _mainView || c.secondItem == _mainView)
       [self.view removeConstraint:c];
```

and it worked.
thanks anyway! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check if self.topLayoutGuide and self.bottomLayoutGuide is not nil. You might have forgotten to set the outlet in Interface Builder.

Comment: SOLVED!!the error is the line "[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];" instead i used "for(NSLayoutConstraint *c in self.view.constraints)
        if(c.firstItem == _mainView || c.secondItem == _mainView)
           [self.view removeConstraint:c];" and it worked.